# Cant access external SSD directory

Tags: samba

I am running my Raspberry Pi with raspbian via ssh. I installed samba in order to run a photo server that everyone at home could access. At first I could find the SSD in `/media/pi` and run samba fine. After some reboots, when trying to access my folder on my PC, It gives me a network Error, the error code is "0x80070035 - The network path was not found". After the error I tried to check what happened with the folder and the SSD, named 'C2F4C67FF4C674E7' was not showing on `/media/pi`.

I have the SSD connected via USB 2.0

I tried to check if it was a connection error within the Raspberry Pi and the SSD so I did `sudo fdisk -l`.

The output was the micro SD installed on the Raspberry Pi and the SSD showed up.

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 58 GiB, 62239277056 bytes, 121561088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbea7937c

Device         Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192    532479    524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 121561087 121028608 57.7G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model:  GP-GSTFS31240GN
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3102DA00-77A7-436A-95C2-A4B9729E6DBB

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1081343   1079296   527M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2    1081344   2002943    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3    2002944   2207743    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda4    2207744 465819696 463611953 221.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  465821696 466833407   1011712   494M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  466835456 467845119   1009664   493M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  467845120 468860927   1015808   496M Microsoft basic data
```

So as far as I know the SSD is connected but I cant acces it

Comment: So you're relying on the automounter in the PiOS file manager? Do you still log in to the GUI? Do none of the SSD partitions shpw up in /media/pi? What is the output of the `mount` command? Did you change any options in the file manager? Have you tried mounting any of the partitions manually? Please update your question wilth relevant details.

Comment: You appear to have deleted your earlier question without responding to questions. Why should anyone ask again?

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell what the `mount` status of your SSD is from your question (at least I can't). You didn't explain **how** you `mount`-ed your drive - or if you did. You should know that having a drive "plugged into" a USB port **does not** mean it has been mounted.

To see whether or not your drive is mounted, run this simple command, and post the results in an edit to your question:

```bsh
lsblk --fs.
```

The output will show if (and where) the SSD drive is mounted. If it's not mounted, you must `mount` it. If you want it to be mounted each time your system boots, you will need to set that up in your `/etc/fstab` file.

Post your results from `lsblk --fs`, and we can proceed from there if you have further questions.